# Change class based string within an alt tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a clever way to do this? It doesn't have to work across all browsers as it's only supplementary but I wondered if there is a quick way round this.

I'm using Cycle2 to create a slider, which has captions that come from the alt text. E.g:

```
<img src="images/data/sports/netball.png" alt="Netball">
```

This displays a caption underneath the icon with "Netball" in.

At present these can all only be one colour (default black) as they use the same class for every caption, as it scrolls through.

```
<div id="alt-caption" class="center"></div>
```

I don't really want to start hacking up the code as it works quite well, but I thought it would be good to make each caption a different text colour, to match the colour of the icon.

Is there a way to do this? e.g using Javascript, grab the data inside the alt (e.g grab "Netball" and make it put this in the class of the caption so it would read:

```
<div id="alt-caption" class="center Netball"></div>
```

Because these are constantly changing it needs to replace "netball" classname with the alt for the next icon (e.g "football")

Live example see the sports section: http://fh80.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/fyp/#

Comment: You can use `$("img").attr("alt")` and `$("#alt-caption").removeClass();` + `$("#alt-caption").addClass(gottenAltAttr)` + `$("#alt-caption").addClass("center")` (or you can remember the last class that was added so you could replace that class with the new one only)

Comment: @robertc because the caption is not part of the image, the CSS doesn't work for changing the colour of the caption. There is only one caption div for many images.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var className = $('img').attr('alt');
$('#alt-caption').addClass(className);
```

Not sure what the selector on your image could be since `img` is quite global? Perhaps it has a parent with a unique ID?

See my fiddle for a basic demonstration

http://jsfiddle.net/9vJLp/4/